# cv2.VideoCapture(url) livestream not working Ubuntu

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, object-detection, video-capture

**Expected outcome:**

I want to make object detection on a livestream.

**My code:**

---

```
    import cv2
    cap=cv2.VideoCapture()
    url='http://192.168.10.1/media/?action=stream'
    cap.open(url)
```

**Error returned:**

`int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'`

What can i do? I've tried everything

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a614a1702e15f42ede5100014ce7f48ed), cap.open(), Opens a video file or a capturing device or an IP video stream for video capturing. I hope the code below will solve the problem using numpy and requests libraries.

```
import requests
import cv2
import numpy as np  
url = ('http://192.168.10.1/media/?action=stream')
stream = requests.get(url, stream=True)  
bytes=''  
while(True):
    bytes+=stream.raw.read(1024)
    a = bytes.find('\xff\xd8')
    b = bytes.find('\xff\xd9')
    if a!=-1 and b!=-1:
        jpg = bytes[a:b+2]
        bytes= bytes[b+2:]
        img = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8),cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        cv2.imshow('Live',img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) ==27:
            exit(0)
```

Comment: hello, i fixed the problem meanwhile. I found that the stream was actually a lot of images (from html code). I changed the url to : http://192.168.10.1/media/?action=stream%00d.jpeg and it worked